# Issue while trying to code FormClosing

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB project for school. When the user tries to close the form, I have to create a message box with YesNo style. If the user presses "Yes", the application closes; if the user presses "No" then they go back to the program screen. The problem is when I press "No" the application still closes and I don't know if VB is glitching but it displays two message boxes. I'm fairly new to VB (started last month). Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim closing As MsgBoxResult
    closing = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question,)
    If closing = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Comment: The FormClosing event is raised when it is already busy closing.  Calling Application.Exit() does not make it close any faster.  You want to test for MsgBoxResult.No and set e.Cancel = True.  And be sure to not display the message box when the user tries to shut down his machine, e.CloseReason is important.  And consider to get rid of this code completely, the user is *always* sure so nagging him about it just annoys him.   If you wrote code that allows the user to accidentally close the window, or lose an hour of his life when he does, then you need to fix *that* code.

Answer (score 2):

The `FormClosing` event occurs when the closing is already started.

You need to cancel the closing, instead of calling `Application.Exit`.
The call of `Application.Exit` triggers the closing event again. Thus the MessageBox appears twice.

Just set the `e.Cancel = True` if the result of the `MessageBox` is `No`:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're probably right, but we don't know if closing form1 will actually end the application so better to keep that in there.

Comment: @Dale_dale12 Yes, but when Form1 is the startup Form then it will close the app, if the default project-settings are not changed. But calling Application.Exit again will trigger the Form closing event again and show the messagebox twice.

Comment: Makes sense, that will be why they were seeing two message boxes. I didn't realise that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in the Form.Closing event unless you call `e.Cancel = True` the form will close.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim closing As MsgBoxResult
    closing = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question,)
    If closing = MsgBoxResult.No Then 
         e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```